# ASP.NET MVC: RenderPartial for a static HTML file

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm sure this is an easy one for most of you ... What is the best way to inject static HTML (from a html file on disc) into a View?

I want something along the lines of this:

```
<%= Html.RenderPartial(pathToMyHtmlFile) %>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

WriteFile from the Response object might do what you want:

```
<% Response.WriteFile(pathToMyHtmlFile); %>
```