# jQuery - ASP.NET MVC - .load and RenderPartial

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

For some specific reasons, I need to use the jQuery 'load()' method in order to feed a webpage into a div layer.

Most of these webpages are plain .html files.

However for some, there is some data processing going on - I would like to be able to leverage the ASP.NET MVC model (which the site is built in) - but that's not possible with plain .html pages - so I need to use .aspx/.ascx.

I'm wondering if this is doable, does anyone know if I can load a layer that is retrieved from an .ascx ViewPage in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more please? I am not clear on what your asking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The html that you need to generate using the view model can be done in a partial view.

create the partial view (partialview.ascx) and in the controller create the method to get the ActionResult

```
public ActionResult partialview(){
   //your code
   return partialview(model);
}
```

now in your html page, use a

```
$.get("controller/partialview", {any data you want to send}, function(html) {
    $("#divToLoad").html(html);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a render partial method for static html files also.  You can check this question out on how:  [ASP.Net MVC: RenderPartial for a static HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196379/asp-net-mvc-renderpartial-for-a-static-html-file)

Comment: No, this isn't quite what I mean... 

I have an html file, and within it, I need to draw a partial view, or call upon one. It can't be an .aspx/.ascx, it has to be a .html file.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm not understanding something, you could easily do this through a number of means.

For instance, you could setup a route of '....../{filename}.html' which spits out the HTML file as a string, you could convert all of the HTML files over to .ascx files and return a partial view.. and so on and so forth.

Comment: Can I bother you to elaborate on this? I'm very new to MVC's routing and what it can do/already does.

Comment: The biggest reason I cannot use a static .html file is because I need to do some work with a view model in some situations.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, all you have to do is to return

```
PartialView()
```

instead of

```
View()
```

(or whatever you return in normal conditions) in your called action.

Comment: I cannot use PartialView, It isn't being returned to an MVC page, it's being returned to a plain, normal .html page. That's my problem.

I need to draw a partial view inside of a normal .html page.