# Render HTML file in ASP.NET MVC view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my view, would like to render the contents of an HTML file as a partial view. It is giving me this error though when I add this to the .cshtml view:

```
@Html.Partial(Url.Content("~/Test/main.html"))
```

Errors:

```
Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The partial view '/Scripts/main.html' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
/Scripts/main.html
```

The file is physically there though. Is there a different way I should be doing this?

Comment: It can be done using Response.WriteFile(pathToMyHtmlFile) -see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196379/asp-net-mvc-renderpartial-for-a-static-html-file/1196440#1196440

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can't use `Html.Partial` for this.It is a special helper method for rendering Partial Views. Instead you can add an `Action` like this:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult GetHtmlPage(string path)
{
   return new FilePathResult(path, "text/html");
}
```

And you can call it from your `View` with using [`Html.Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703423%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) helper Method:

```
@Html.Action("GetHtmlPage","controllername", new { path = "~/Test/main.html" })
```

Comment: Beware, this opens up a vulnerability as anyone could use that controller action to get any file on your website. The easiest fix is to apply the `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute to the controller action so that it can't be accessed directly by the browser.

Comment: How can we alter this if we wish to take the result from an actual HTML page from the internet?

Comment: @Selman Genç Per @Slight's comment, please edit your answer to include the `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute so that others won't simply copy and paste your code without looking at the comments. I just tested it without that attribute, and I can look at my web.config, etc.

Answer (score 7):

Follow these steps

1. Create a view in `~/views/shared` folder. give it name `test.cshtml`.
2. Copy the content of HTML in it.
3. Use `Html.Partial("test")` on page to render the html of that view.

Answer (score 6):

I think it's a better solution:
Use `WriteFile` from the `Response` object

```
@Response.WriteFile(pathToMyHtmlFile)
```

taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1196440/281048)

Answer (score 5):

The simple answer is to rename the main.html file to main.cshtml which will be recognized by the Razor view engine for rendering.

Answer (score 3):

You could use this in your cshtml view:

```
@{this.GetOutputWriter().Write(File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("/your/static/file.html")));}
```

Answer (score 1):

A total different way is just load the file in javascript

```
<div id="loadId">
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#loadId').load('filepath');
    });
</script>
```

You can set the filepath in the controller, or put it in the model, if you want, and use:

```
$('#loadId').load('@ViewBag.filepath');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use an ajax request to fetch the html file output the content into your main html. Since it is an html file, it will be cached in subsequent calls and there will be no performance impact.