# open a new window form action method in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to open a url from the javascript function.

The issue is I am not able to authorize it the url mentioned in the image.

How can I load the page from the action method so that i can authorize the url.

Here is my Javascript method.

```
<img src="~/Images/question_frame.png" style="margin-top:3px;height:18px;width:20px;" onclick="window.open('../help/nmc/enu/default.htm', 'NMCHelp', 'toolbar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=50, left=50, width=750, height=600');"/>
```

How can i achieve this?

How do i get the window.open(.../help/nmc/enu/default.htm) to opened from the action method in a new window so that when anyone tried to open the window with out authorized will be redirected to login page.

Comment: Navigate to a controller method with the `[Authorize]` attribute (not to a static file)

Answer (score 2):

You're displaying a static HTML file, which will bypass MVC entirely.

The easiest would be to create an authorized action method and link to that instead. Then in the action method, return the contents of the HTML file. See [Render HTML file in ASP.NET MVC view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20871938/render-html-file-in-asp-net-mvc-view).

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. Its working fine for html files.Iam trying to open .htm file.whcih is giveing me issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31109892/need-help-in-opening-htm-file-in-mvc