# Need help in opening .htm file in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC4 and Jquery.

I am having issue in opening the .htm file through action method in MVC.

Here is my Code:

```
<img src="~/Images/question_frame.png" style="margin-top:3px;height:18px;width:20px;" onclick="window.open('@Url.Action("Help", "Home", new { id = "NMCHelp"})', 'NMCHelp',toolbar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=50, left=50,width=750, height=600');"/>
```

My ActionMethod:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Help(){
    var result = new FilePathResult("~/help/nmc/enu/Default.htm", "text/html");![enter image description here][1]
    return result;
}
```

I am facing issue while trying to open.I am getting error like 
**'$'is undefined.**

Please let me know how can I open the .htm file through action method

Answer (score 1):

Don't try and return it as a `FilePathResult,` there's no need to overcomplicate things here. Firstly, put your HTM file inside a folder in your project, something like `Files`.

Now, add the following to your web.config to prevent unauthorised access to your file:

```
<location path="Files">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

And then you can link to it by doing:

```
<img src="~/Images/question_frame.png" 
    style="margin-top:3px;height:18px;width:20px;" 
    onclick="window.open('/Files/Default.htm', 'NMCHelp',toolbar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=50, left=50,width=750, height=600');"/>
```

While you're at it, you might want to think about removing those inline styles and use a class name and the inline JavaScript too.

Comment: i tried with this but it is not working or authenticating.Even when i tried to use the url to open htm file its opening with out asking for authenticatiion

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating a controller entry for this? It's a plain .htm file, you can just browse the to the .htm file directly:

```
<img src="~/Images/question_frame.png" style="margin-top:3px;height:18px;width:20px;" onclick="window.open('/help/nmc/enu/Default.htm', 'toolbar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=50, left=50, width=750, height=600');" />
```

Alternatively your option is to turn the file into a .cshtml file in which case you can use the controller to just `return View()`, make sure you give the .cshtml file the right name and drop it in the correct folder.

Comment: I want to apply authorization for the .htm file so that user cannot open directly from outside with out authenticating.I added it to the action method.

Comment: Then you will need to create it as a .cshtml and use the proper MVC way to return a view.

Comment: any help in rendering the .htm file in MVC View.

Comment: You can't, when someone knows the location of the .htm file they can browse there. This is due to .htm not being rendered through the controllers. Alternatively you can look at doing something like .htaccess or some form of folder authentication through IIS. However I would strongly suggest to use the MVC controllers the way they are intended.