# .NET/C# How to render static HTML from a separate folder with relative referenced content

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm developing a custom CMS. I have content per ResearchArticle stored in Azure blobs. The content consists of an index.html file with any related images, pdf's etc. the index.html page uses relative local references as in:

```
<img src="chuck-norris-1.jpg" />
```

This is so our designer can make articles with related content and put it all in one folder to be sent to an Azure blob container. Each web server then downloads the content into a local ResearchArticle content folder structure as in:

```
ResearchArticleBodyLocal\abc
```

So, now I have to display this content when someone views the article. I was reading the index.html into a string and using @Html.raw(). Problem is, from the view, the relative references aren't working because the view, obviously, is in a different location than the content.

but #1 the relative references are off, and #2 for some reason it's running the action method twice as if it has a jQuery problem, but I'm not using any JQuery here...

Here's what I'm trying:

controller method-

`ravm.ArticleBodyIndexHtmlPath = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ResearchArticleBodyRelativeLocalDirectory"] + researchArticle.BodyRelativeLocalPath + "/index.html"));`

View -

```
@(Html.Raw(Model.ArticleBodyIndexHtmlPath))
```

I've also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20871938/render-html-file-in-asp-net-mvc-view) but the relative reference thing is still a problem... Anyone have a vision of how to solve this without having the designer put the intended directory structure into the content references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I wound up doing this:

```
 private List<string> GetFilePathsAndUpdateIndexHtml(string bodyFolderChoices, string containerName)
    {
        // get path to each item
        var filePaths =
            Directory.GetFiles(
                Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ResearchArticleFTPUploadRoot"] + "/" +
                               bodyFolderChoices));
        // get root from web.config
        var azureRootUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureBlobRootUrl"] + containerName + "/";
        // find index.html and replace relative references
        foreach (var s in filePaths)
        {
            if (s.Contains("index.html"))
            {
                var doc = new HtmlDocument();
                doc.LoadHtml(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(s));
                HtmlNodeCollection links = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@background or @lowsrc or @src or @href]");
                if (links == null)
                    continue;
                foreach (HtmlNode link in links)
                {
                    // references to outside URLs this will break unless we check for 'http' and leave alone
                    if (link.Attributes["background"] != null && !link.Attributes["background"].Value.Contains("http"))
                        link.Attributes["background"].Value = azureRootUrl + link.Attributes["background"].Value;
                    if (link.Attributes["href"] != null && !link.Attributes["href"].Value.Contains("http"))
                        link.Attributes["href"].Value = azureRootUrl + link.Attributes["href"].Value;
                    if (link.Attributes["lowsrc"] != null && !link.Attributes["lowsrc"].Value.Contains("http"))
                        link.Attributes["lowsrc"].Value = azureRootUrl + link.Attributes["lowsrc"].Value;
                    if (link.Attributes["src"] != null && !link.Attributes["src"].Value.Contains("http"))
                        link.Attributes["src"].Value = azureRootUrl + link.Attributes["src"].Value;
                }
                doc.Save(s);
            }
        }
        return filePaths.ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could perhaps put the directory structure there using a bit of string replacement/regex? I do that within my own templating system so that the designer can do src="chuck-norris.jpg" and I replace it depending on the site being hit with src="/othersite-image-dir/chuck-norris.jpg" automatically. That way my designer doesn't have to remember directories.

The other way around it is to have a specific directory structure for your objects, i.e

images

js

css

That way the designer can go src="/js/my-chuck-norris.js" and always hit the file regardless of which site it's in

Comment: Hmm.. I wanted to avoid string games as it's never fun or pretty especially since I don't know what the HTMl will be. Some of the anchor tags might point to other websites and appending directory structure would break those... I'm going to keep looking for a better answer.. I'll circle back in a day or so. thanks!

Comment: I played string games anyway.. but it solved the problem. thanks